# Drupal 6 content type different templates ( or different themes ) subsites

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6, themes, contenttype

mysite have follow directories:
mysite/sites/all/themes/a
mysite/sites/all/themes/b
mysite/sites/all/themes/c
There are 3 content types:a, b,c. And each type I want to use the tpl file under his directory.
That is to say, if I create a content of which content type is a. And this content will use the tpl file under this directory mysite/sites/all/themes/a/page.tpl.php (node.tpl.php, template.tpl.php)
So how to do this?
By the way, I also use the "subsites", so when i create a content, i can choose from the subsites list: "none" "a" "b" "c". 
So how to associate the template/theme to the content type or the subsite option?

[Because the problem is: if i create a content of type "b" and do not choose the subsites(choose "none"), and this content will use "a"template. And then if i choose the subsite "b", it won't work.][If I create the content "b" and choose the subsite "b", then this content will be "b"template.][If I create the content "b" and choose the subsite "b", and set the "URL path settings",then this content will be "a"template. I think "a" is the default template.] So I have no idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

This module is available for Drupal 6.x and seems to do exactly what you want.
http://drupal.org/project/content_theme

It's generally a good idea when attempting something with Drupal to search for modules that implement it.

I found this searching on the following search:
https://www.google.se/search?q=drupal+multiple+themes&oq=drupal+multiple+themes&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

In a comment on the first hit:
http://drupal.org/node/107755#comment-6035558

Update: I hope this helps. I am not clear on what you mean by "subsites".